can we use Keras Sequential model with dense layers for non-temporal data
can we use Keras Sequential model with dense layers for non-temporal data
i want to use deep learning methods with a tabular dataset of depression i found that we can use  keras sequential model with dese layer but my teacher told me that we can use sequential model only for temporal data

I think you are confusing Sequential with a sequence model, only the latter is meant for temporal or sequence data.
